# Lambda Expressions: Returning Multiple Values

Tags: python, lambda

I want to implement the function via a lambda expression as follows:

Instead of this:

```
def f(x, y, z):
     return x + 1, y * 2, z * 3
```

I want to use a lambda expression, like this:

```
f = lambda x, y, z: x + 1, y * 2, z * 3
```

The stacktrace:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined*
```

Why is this causing an error? How can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

Your tuple is not binding correctly - the lambda is ending at the first comma. Put parens around the tuple:

```
f=lambda x,y,z: (x+1,y*2,z*3)
```

Comment: To add to @Austin the return in a function does not need the parenthesis. The notation `return a,b,c` returns a tuple `(a,b,c)` implicitly

Comment: Lambda function returns are different from regularly defined functions. The parens are necessary.